# Member function of templated class

Tags: c++, templates

I am new to templates and i have some troube understanding this piece of code

```
template <typename T>
class Item
{
  T data;
  public:
   Item <T> ():data(T())
   { 
     cout<<"inside constructor for Item class"<<endl;}
     void setdata(T nvalue){
     data=nvalue;
   }
      Item <T> operator +(int s){
      return Item <T> (data + s);
   }
      T getdata() const
      {
        //T temp =data[0];
         return data;
         }
     void printdata()
      {
       cout<<data<<endl;
      }
};
```

The part which i don't understand is the function

```
Item <T> operator +(int s){
  return Item <T> (data + s);
}
```

I understand that operator '+' is being overloaded here but i don't understand what is the function of `Item <T>` in the `return` statement and before `operator + (int s)`

Comment: That's constructor, right?

Comment: @billz No idea ,i thought `Item <T> ():data(T())` was the constructor.

Comment: I mean that's calling the constructor to construct an object.

Comment: @billz Now that you tell me it does look like a constructor. Can i write some code in main() so that `Item <T> operator +(int s)` constructor is called? If i write `Item <int> item1(2)` then i think  the first one will be called

Comment: @billz i read that return statements are not allowed in a constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have this code:

```
Item<int> myItem;

Item<int> myItem2 = myItem + 3;
```

This will create and instance of the template (this is different from a instance of a class)

Note: there was an error in your original code, you are missing the declaration of a consutrctor:

```
Item <T> (T num):data(num)
{ 
  cout<<"inside constructor for Item class"<<endl;
}
```

This will look like this:

```
class Item
{
    int data;
    public:
        Item <int> (int num):data(num)
        { 
            cout<<"inside constructor for Item class"<<endl;
        }

        Item <int> ():data(int())
        { 
            cout<<"inside constructor for Item class"<<endl;
        }

        void setdata(int nvalue)
        {
            data=nvalue;
        }

        Item<int> operator +(int s)
        {
            return Item <int> (data + s);
        }

        int getdata() const
        {
           return data;
        }

        void printdata()
        {
           cout<<data<<endl;
        }
};
```

Btw this class will only work if T can be added with an int.

```
Item<int> myItem2 = myItem + 3;
```

The result of

> myItem + 3

Will be a new Item that presumably now contains the value data from myItem plus 3 (myItem2);

Comment: Thanks for answer.You were right about the error in the code.I have tried out what you have suggested and it worked.But i see that the code also works if i write the operator + overloading as `int operator +(int s) { return (data+s);}` ,so the code `Item <T>` before the return statement is optional?

Comment: @gautam do you want `Item<T>+int` to be an `int` or an `Item<T>`?

Comment: @Yakk I did not understand ,what i did was write code like this`Item<int> myItem2=myItem+3` ,with `myItem` object already created and its `data` member initialized with `1` ,I just changed `Item<T> operator +(int s)` to  `int operator +(int s)` ,myItem2.data had value of 4 by the time `Item<int> myItem2=myItem+3` executed so i was wondering what role `Item <T>` in function declaration and return statement played.

Comment: @gautam write a functiin that is overloaded on both `int` and `Item<T>`, snd the different return types will make different overrides being called.  You can convert from an `int` to an `Item<int>` but they are not wuite the same thing.  Regrardless, this is a problem of understanding normal classes not templates.

Comment: @Yakk I tried writing two functions as you suggested and i could see the difference , thanks.